# Javascript Query Builder with MongoDB "$in" operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mlab

So I have set up a query builder that builds a query based on the users interaction with the data filtration area on the front end which contains a lot of radio buttons and dropdown boxes etc. Similar to what eBays data filtration function provided on their website.

**My Query Builder so far:**

```
app.post('/user/test',function(req, res) {

var query = {};


if (req.body.region){
    query.region = req.body.region
    console.log(query.region)
}

if(req.body.sector){
    query.sector = req.body.sector
    console.log(query.sector)
}

if(req.body.client){
    query.client = req.body.client
    console.log(query.client)
}

   Project.find(query, function(err, project){
    if (err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    console.log(project);
    res.json(project);
});
});
```

Now the above works very well. I can send filtration options in any scenario and it will bring back the required result. For example I can only send the region name and it will give me all the data that belongs to that region or I can send region name, sector name and it will further filter down the data that matches region and sector name sent and so on.

**The Issue:**

Now my database contains an array of data like:

```
words: ["book", "table", "pen"]
```

Each object in the database will have this array. So if there are 100 objects in the database each has one of these will have the "words" array  with different or similar values.

I want to be able to send multiple options like "table" , "pen" to my database and get all the objects that contains the those two options within the data array.

To achieve that I did the following:

```
 if (req.body.sol){

    var arr = [];
    arr.push(req.body.sol)
    query.words = {words: {$in: arr}}
}
```

The above **Did not work**.

But if I make the following changes to this line:

**From**

```
query.words = {words: {$in: arr}}
```

**to**

```
query = {words: {$in: arr}}
```

**Making the above change does work but then it does not build the remaining queries. It only builds the "$in" query.**

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)** to add the **`$in`** operator in your query properties:

```
if (req.body.sol){
    var arr = [],
        obj = {};    

    arr.push(req.body.sol);
    obj["$in"] = arr;
    query.words = obj;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can simply write the query like

```
query.words = {$in: arr}
```

This way you would be able to build rest of the query.

---

the reason why `query.words = {words: {$in: arr}}` fails is that the query becomes`{words:{words: {$in: arr}}}`, which is not what you want, since its trying to find words inside words.

instead using `query.words = {$in: arr}` will make your query `{words: {$in: arr}`

Comment: ahhh. That clears it up such a silly mistake. Thank you that really helped.